# Migrating host and ComponentResolver from AngularDart 4 to 5

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I'm busy migrating a large Angular4 application (that was just migrated from Angular2) to Angular5.

In several places in the application, we make use of a directive to tag a div or other html element which then gets generated inside that component, in this case the `contentItem` directive is used to indicate that the div should be generated in the center of the layout whereas the `footerItem` indicated that the div should be generated at the bottom of the page layout.

```
<standard-layout
        (print)="handlePrintReport(\$event)"
        [hideScrollbars]="true">
        <div class="content-main-1" *contentItem>
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="content-main-2" *contentItem>
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="something-else" *footerItem>
            ...
        <div>
</standard-layout>
```

Inside StandardLayout,

```
<div 
    class="content-scroller" 
    [class.margin-auto]="contentScrollerMarginAuto"
    [class.overflow-hidden]="hideScrollbars">
    <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="contentItems [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFun">
        <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.template"></template>
    </template>
</div>
```

and

```
@ContentChildren(ContentItemDirective)
List<ContentItemDirective> contentItems;

@ContentChildren(ContentItemFooterDirective)
List<ContentItemFooterDirective> contentItemFooters;
```

In my `ContentItemDirective`, `ComponentResolver` no longer compiles, is there a drop-in replacement for it or do i require major changes to make this work in Angular5?

```
@Directive(selector: "[contentItem]")
class ContentItemDirective implements AfterContentInit {

    int id = IdProvider.generateIntIndex();

    final ViewContainerRef vcRef;
    final TemplateRef template;
    final ComponentResolver componentResolver;

    ContentItemDirective(this.vcRef, this.template, this.componentResolver);

    ComponentRef componentRef;

    @override
    ngAfterContentInit() async {
        final componentFactory =
        await componentResolver.resolveComponent(ContentItem);
        componentRef = vcRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        (componentRef.instance as ContentItem)
            ..template = template;
    }
}
```

Then in my component factory, `host` no longer compiles, i guess i can just move that css-class injection into StandardLayout or is there an Angular5 way of doing this?

```
@Component(
    selector: "content-item",
    template: "",
    host: const {
        "[class.content-item]": "true",
    }
)
class ContentItem {

    int id = IdProvider.generateIntIndex();

    TemplateRef template;
}
```

TLDR, how do i migrate `ComponentResolver` and the `host` property inside `@Component` annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

host attributes on the Component change to @HostBindings or @HostListener annotations. In this case:

```
@HostBinding('class.content-item')
static const bool contentItemClass = true;
```

For the resolver you need to import the factory itself. Import the template.dart file for the ContentItem component. So if that file is content_item.dart you would import content_item.template.dart.

Then just use the type ContentItemNgFactory instead of doing the lookup using the type.

Comment: This is correct. The pattern used by ComponentResolver *drastically* affects code size, as it effectively prevents Dart from tree-shaking *any* of your components. Behind the scenes it had to maintain a map of Type to ComponentFactory.

So while less ergonomic, importing the generated file and using the generated ComponentFactory directly allows the compiler to tree-shake any unused components from your app (which matters a lot if you're importing a library that contains many components, and you only use a few).

Comment: Continued working on this part today and got it working, thanks for the hints.
Posted a mostly working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56791433/passing-multiple-parameters-to-a-structural-directive-in-angulardart-5/56791609#56791609