# Passing multiple parameters to a structural directive in AngularDart 5

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I want to pass in multiple params to a structural directive, but what was working in Angular2 doesn't seem to work in Angular5 anymore

Here's my `blah` component which contains an accordion:

```
@Component(
    selector: "blah-scene",
    // language=HTML
    template: """
        <div>
            Blah Test Page
            <accordion>
                <div *accordionItem>
                    item1
                </div>
                <div *accordionItem>
                    item2
                </div>
            </accordion>
        </div>
    """,
    directives: const [
        Accordion,
        AccordionItemDirective
    ]
)
class BlahScene implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {
...
}
```

Accordion is defined as follow:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'accordion',
    // language=HTML
    template: """
    <ul class="accordion"
        [id]="id"
        [attr.data-slide-speed]="slideSpeed"
        [attr.data-multi-expand]="multiExpand"
        [attr.data-allow-all-closed]="allowAllClosed">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ul>
    """,
    styles: const ["""
        .overflow-hidden {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    """
    ],
)
class Accordion implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {

    @ContentChildren(AccordionItemDirective)
    List<AccordionItemDirective> items;

    ...

}
```

I'm expecting those two divs marked with `*accordionItem` to be rendered as accordion items which it does.

AccordionItem:

```
@Component(
    selector: "li",
    template: """
    <a
        *ngIf="visible"
        class="accordion-title"
        [attr.did]="title"
        (click)='onClickTitle(title)'>
        {{title?.toUpperCase()}}
        <img
            src="{{expandButtonPath()}}"
            class="expand-navbar"
            [class.disabled]='!allowClose && active'>
    </a>

    <div
        class="accordion-content no-padding"
        [class.hidden]='!active'
        [class.overflow-hidden]="hideScrollBars"
        [class.overflow-auto]="!hideScrollBars"
        data-tab-content>
        <template
            [ngIf]="renderAccordionItemContent && visible"
            [ngTemplateOutlet]="template">
        </template>
    </div>
    """,
    styles: const ["""
        ...
    """],
    directives: const [
        NgTemplateOutlet,
        coreDirectives
    ]
)
class AccordionItem implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {

    TemplateRef template;

   ...

}
```

And then the `AccordionItemDirective` which creates the AccordionItem and adds it to the DOM:

```
@Directive(selector: '[accordionItem]')
class AccordionItemDirective implements AfterContentInit {

    final ViewContainerRef vcRef;
    final TemplateRef template;

    AccordionItemDirective(this.vcRef, this.template);

    AccordionItem accordionItem;

    ComponentRef componentRef;
    String accordionId;

    @override
    ngAfterContentInit() async {

        template.createEmbeddedView();

        final ComponentRef<AccordionItem> component =
            vcRef.createComponent(accordionItemTemplate.AccordionItemNgFactory);
        accordionItem = component.instance;

        accordionItem
            ..template = template
            ..active = _accordionItemActive
            ..title = accordionItemTitle
            ..accordionId = accordionId;

    }

...
```

Up to here, it works fine, the AccordionItems are created and inserted as `li` inside the accordion

[image]

I now want to pass in params so that i can set the title and id and some other properties of that accordionItem
On the accordionItemDirective, i add some inputs:

```
@Input("accordionItemId") String accordionItemId = "";
bool _accordionItemActive = false;

@Input("accordionItemTitle")
String accordionItemTitle = "Missing Title";
```

Expecting this to work:

```
<accordion>
    <div *accordionItem [accordionItemTitle]="'Title1'">
        item1
    </div>
    <div *accordionItem>
        item2
    </div>
</accordion>
```

i get this error:

> lib/component/test/blah-scene.dart: ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Can't bind
>   to 'accordionItemTitle' since it isn't a known native property or
>   known directive. Please fix typo or add to directives list.

Trying it without the square brackets:

```
<accordion>
    <div *accordionItem accordionItemTitle="'Title1'">
        item1
    </div>
    <div *accordionItem>
        item2
    </div>
</accordion>
```

it compiles, but nothing happens.

I try to intercept the input, but my log.fines aren't being printed at all

```
@Input("accordionItemTitle")
set accordionItemTitle(String title) {
    log.fine(title);
}
String get accordionItemTitle {
    return "Missing Title [...]";
}
```

In Angular2, this used to work:

```
        <accordion>
            <div *accordionItem="accordionItemTitle: 'Title1' ">
                item1
            </div>
            <div *accordionItem>
                item2
            </div>
        </accordion>
```

but that too is complaining:

> ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Can't bind to 'accordionItemAccordionItemTitle'
>   since it isn't an input of any bound directive. Please check that the
>   spelling is correct, and that the intended directive is included in
>   the host component's list of directives

What is the correct way to pass in parameters to a structural directive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this works for all inputs other than `accordionItemId`:

```
        <accordion>
            <div *accordionItem="title: 'Title1'; active: true ">
                item1
            </div>
            <div *accordionItem="title: 'Title2'; active: true ">
                item2
            </div>
        </accordion>
```

Comment: The syntax is a bit weird but you can see ngFor as an example: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/e87e51f61b3f1700a9482b77679afd7fe8cd3eb5/angular/lib/src/common/directives/ng_for.dart

Does *accordionItem="id: 'id'" not work? I guess it could be reserved somehow